# Unexplained changes in reputation, values "jump" wildly

Tags: support, reputation

this is what my reputation tab looks like for today:

[image]

This does not make any sense whatsoever.

- I've not hit the rep cap today, not by far. I could account for 5 or 6 up-votes at most.
- All up-votes happened at the same time (around 16:15 GMT). Really?
- Previous days seem to have lost rep count. At least they don't have the values I remember. I'm not sure.
- This awkward behavior has been going on a few days, at least since 20 January.
  *(On that day I first noticed that I've hit the rep cap in mid-day. This surprised me. Consequently, all following up-votes did not count. Looking at that day now reveals a counter of merely 78 rep.)*

Can any of the devs explain what's going on? (If this is some kind announced maintenance, please excuse my ignorance.)

Comment: You could simply be the victim of one (or several) serial-upvoters.

Comment: @Mat I don't think so. I believe I've noticed that the times when the up-votes occurred have changed, as if they've been re-calculated several times. Also, one answer has two up-votes at the same time.

Comment: I don't see that answer with two simultaneous upvotes - for the only on I see with two upvotes today, they were cast three hours apart. The (daily?) serial-vote deleter script would produce something like what you see if your are continuously serial-upvoted.

Comment: It looks 'normal' now, typical caching problem.  Somebody is methodically upvoting your answers.  And you'll lose the votes when the anti-cheat script removes them again.  Up and down is the result.

Comment: @UphillLuge Why would anybody do this? I'm not entirely convinced, yet.

Comment: This is almost always a grateful user that doesn't know how to use votes appropriately.  You can possibly trace him if you remember exactly when the votes started.  Or email team@stackoverflow.com to ask for a trace.

Comment: Votes are anonymous; however, all diamond mods can look at voting patterns to determine if somebody's involved in sock puppet voting or voteringing. I just checked, and didn't find anything suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reputation is fluctuating suddenly and without warning (i.e. going up by a lot, then coming back down a few hours later), then it's the vote fraud script doing its work with serial upvoters. It's not a bug, and nothing to worry about.

If you're really concerned about your reputation (I mean, *who isn't*?), remember that you can manually recalculate your reputation once every 24 hours, by going to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation.

By the way, [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak?tab=reputation) looks fine to me now:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. (I've also written an email to the team, as Uphill Luge suggested. Maybe that was unnecessary.) Definitely some tampering has been going on since Friday, I'll keep an eye on it. I'd not be surprised when these votes are gone at the end of the day, because this is looking anything but good to me.

Comment: Oh that's alright. It's always good to have more eyeballs on matters like this.

Comment: *Now* the rep tab is looking fine. Seems to be some overly eager up-voter after all.